# Как преобразовать строку в число?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ребят подскажите, как преобразовать строку в число оптимально.

Есть список со вложенными списками:

```
price = [['MOSCOW-LONDON:', '120', 'EUR'], ['LONDON-NEWYORK:', '235', 'USD'],
         ['NEWYORK-BRASILIA:', '112', 'BRL'], ['BRASILIA-PEKING:', '243', 'CNY'],
         ['PEKING-SEOUL:', '97', 'KRW'], ['SEOUL-DELHI:', '130', 'INR'],
         ['DELHI-MOSCOW:', '19526', 'RUB']]
```

Мне нужно `price[1]` перевести в `int`.

Как лучше всего это сделать?

Comment: int(price[0][1])

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Ознакомьтесь

Answer (score 2):

Зная индекс числа, вы можете пройтись по списку  добавить все числа в список таким образом:

```
lst = []
for x in price:
    lst.append(int(x[1]))
```

А если не знаете, то нужно добавить дополнительную проверку:

```
lst = []
for x in price:
    for j in x:
    if j.isdigit():
        lst.append(int(j)) # если работаете или нужны числа с плавающей точкой, то float(j)
```

Таким образом в списке **lst** будут нужные вам данные

Если вы хотите просто преобразовать список, то вам нужно использовать конструкцию `list comprehension`:

Так можно получить один список со всеми данными, где числа уже будут преобразованы в тип `int`:

```
price = [['MOSCOW-LONDON:', '120', 'EUR'], ['LONDON-NEWYORK:', '235', 'USD'],
         ['NEWYORK-BRASILIA:', '112', 'BRL'], ['BRASILIA-PEKING:', '243', 'CNY'],
         ['PEKING-SEOUL:', '97', 'KRW'], ['SEOUL-DELHI:', '130', 'INR'],
         ['DELHI-MOSCOW:', '19526', 'RUB']] 

price = [int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for x in price for y in x]

print(price)

# ['MOSCOW-LONDON:', 120, 'EUR', 'LONDON-NEWYORK:', 235, 'USD', 'NEWYORK-BRASILIA:', 112, 'BRL', 'BRASILIA-PEKING:', 243, 'CNY', 'PEKING-SEOUL:', 97, 'KRW', 'SEOUL-DELHI:', 130, 'INR', 'DELHI-MOSCOW:', 19526, 'RUB']
```

А так можно сохранить текущую размерность и также преобразовать числа:

```
price = [['MOSCOW-LONDON:', '120', 'EUR'], ['LONDON-NEWYORK:', '235', 'USD'],
         ['NEWYORK-BRASILIA:', '112', 'BRL'], ['BRASILIA-PEKING:', '243', 'CNY'],
         ['PEKING-SEOUL:', '97', 'KRW'], ['SEOUL-DELHI:', '130', 'INR'],
         ['DELHI-MOSCOW:', '19526', 'RUB']] 

length = len(price)

for x in range(length):
    price[x] = [int(y) if y.isdigit() else y for y in price[x]]

print(price)
# [['MOSCOW-LONDON:', 120, 'EUR'], ['LONDON-NEWYORK:', 235, 'USD'], ['NEWYORK-BRASILIA:', 112, 'BRL'], ['BRASILIA-PEKING:', 243, 'CNY'], ['PEKING-SEOUL:', 97, 'KRW'], ['SEOUL-DELHI:', 130, 'INR'], ['DELHI-MOSCOW:', 19526, 'RUB']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам приходят данные с запроса , если порядок вложенного листа не будет изменен...

```
price = [['MOSCOW-LONDON:', '120', 'EUR'], ['LONDON-NEWYORK:', '235', 'USD'], ['NEWYORK-BRASILIA:', '112', 'BRL'], ['BRASILIA-PEKING:', '243', 'CNY'], ['PEKING-SEOUL:', '97', 'KRW'], ['SEOUL-DELHI:', '130', 'INR'], ['DELHI-MOSCOW:', '19526', 'RUB']]
all_price = [p[1] for p in price]
>>> ['120', '235', '112', '243', '97', '130', '19526',]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price = [['MOSCOW-LONDON:', '120', 'EUR'], ['LONDON-NEWYORK:', '235', 'USD'], ['NEWYORK-BRASILIA:', '112', 'BRL'], ['BRASILIA-PEKING:', '243', 'CNY'], ['PEKING-SEOUL:', '97', 'KRW'], ['SEOUL-DELHI:', '130', 'INR'], ['DELHI-MOSCOW:', '19526', 'RUB']]
new_price = list()
for item in price:
    item[1] = int(item[1])
    new_price.append(item)
print(new_price)
```

Comment: Зачем создавать новый список, если вы изменяете существующий?

Comment: В вопросе явно не указано нужно ли менять существующий список.